# Changing currency in cart column unit price excluse tax error when currency converted

Tags: php, magento, php-5.3, cart, magento-1.6

I've two store view, one in EUR (primary currency) and the other in Dollar.
Tax is 21% for both stores, included in product price.
In the cart, if I change the store to the Dollar store view, column "Unit Price (Excl. Tax)" isn't correctly calculated. It seems that only on this field currency conversion is done two times.

This is the content of the store

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/546584/cart_problem_DOLLAR.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/546584/cart_problem_EUR.png

Some one can halp me solve this problem?
I've done a lot of debug but can't bring myself out of the tunnel.
Tkis!

Comment: How is the price excl. tax calculated? Can You provide us with the code?

Answer (score 0):

If the store is saving the prices incl. tax, then You'd be careful when calculating the price excl. the tax.

If the tax is 21%, then the price incl. tax is 121% of the price excl. tax, thus the price excl. tax should be calculated like `$priceExclTax = $priceInclTax / 1.21;`.

Answer (score 0):

Download version 1.7.0.2

Copy to local

Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal

That should fix your problem